# Ubuntu при загрузке зависает на Started User Manager for UID 121

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

После расширения дискового пространства на VirtualBox, Ubuntu 18.04 перестала загружаться и виснет на "Started User Manager for UID 121".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то это вылечить без переустановки Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Скачайте live-образ ubuntu, загрузитесь с него (в настойках vm нужно будет выбрать данный iso-образ в меню носителей) и посмотрите что стало с разделами:

`fdisk -l`

и какие ошибки есть в логах.

Comment: А через ctrl + alt + f2 посмотреть fdisk -l - это будет тоже самое?

Comment: да, если терминал доступен через ctr+alt+f2, то liveобраз не потребуется, можно и там посмотреть